# How to drop records from Pandas dataframe but keep an exception?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop all records with Name= Tina, but keep the record if Year =2015

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Amy'], 
        'year': [2015, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2014], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
```

This code df[(df.name != 'Tina') will drop all the records name = Tina, but i need to keep the one with Year = 2015

expected output:

```
     name   reports year
Cochice  Jason  4   2015
Maricopa Tina   2   2015
Yuma     Amy    3   2014
```

Comment: `df[df['name'].ne('Tina') | df['year'].eq(2015)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using drop duplicate keep='last' if record are sorted as you need them.

```
df.drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
```

Output:

```
           name  year  reports
Cochice   Jason  2015        4
Maricopa   Tina  2015        2
Yuma        Amy  2014        3
```